# Failed in making Relation between User and their Post ....!

Tags: php, laravel-5

PostController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Tpost;

class PostController extends Controller
{
   public function createUserPost(Request $request){

     $this->validate($request,[
      'post'=>'required'
      ]);
     $tpost =new Tpost();
     $tpost->body =$request['post'];
     $message = "something wrong";

     if($request->tuser()->tposts()->save($tpost))   //problem is there
     {
      $message = "post Successfully Submited";
     }
     return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with('message',$message);
   }
}
```

---

Tpost.php

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tpost extends Model
{
    //
    public function tuser(){
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Tuser');
    }
}
```

---

Tuser.php

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tuser extends Model  implements  Authenticatable
{
    use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;

    public function tposts(){
     return $this->hasMany('App\Tpost');
    }
```

> Got error: BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 81: Method
>   tuser does not exist.

**//If I use**

```
$tpost ->save();
```

> //simply inserted into database //I thought I failed to make relation
>   between Tuser and Tpost models.
>   In PostController.php, If I do `dd($tpost->tuser());` then it returned an associative array as shown, but If do `dd($request->tuser());` then it says Method tuser does not exist.
>   please Help....

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your method call precisely where you write "problem is there". It should read:

```
if($request->tuser()->tposts()->save($tpost))
```

Edit--

Judging from the error message, it's pretty clear that Laravel thinks you're asking for the tuser() method on the $request instance, which obviously doesn't exist.

Can you use:

```
Auth::user()->tposts()->save($tpost)
```

If this doesn't work, I'd suggest making sure that the config/auth.php file reflects your particular usage case, specifically the User Providers section.

Comment: ty! fixed it but same problem @alex